# Неправильно работает оперативная память

Tags: windows, железо, bios

В компьютере 2 плашки по 8 гб, отдельно обе работают, вместе тоже уже работали, но в новой сборке отказываются. Windows пишет 12 гб (доступно 8 гб). Настройки биоса сбрасывал, память проверял, обе абсолютно рабочие. [Фото биоса и cpu z](https://imgur.com/a/bL8FTeF). Процессор FX-6330, мать GA-78LMT-S2.

Comment: Вы или статикой убили одну плашку или контакты грязные. Ещё есть возможность что повреждён разъём или контакты на плате.